Checking Excel Formula behind xlwings sql function
I have some complicated processing to do on an Excel Table, for which I am using xlwings to basically run SQL over that table using the sql() function:
Example: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM a
Is it possible to check what excel formula(s) xlwings is using behind the scenes to actually execute the query ?
The issue is, I need to send the excel file to my clients and I don't wan't them to install xlwings extension.
Can anyone help on that ?
Thanks in advance.

It's an add-in so who knows what the underlying code is but the developers.Probably a better question for them.
